# What is the influence of mood?

Tags: civcrafter

What is the influence of mood in Civcrafter? Currently it is blissful, which sounds good. However, I have no change in production as far as I can tell. See the attached screenshot. The +20% comes from the clan I am in.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effects of Happiness are as following:

- When workers are angry, production falls drastically. You're fricking
  fricked.
- When workers are unhappy, production goes down, but not to the
  'angry' level. You're alright (for now.)
- When workers are content, production stays the same. You aight.
- When workers are happy, production increases. You're doing fine.
- When workers are blissful, production increases by 1.5x. You're doing
  gooooooooood

From: https://civ-clicker.fandom.com/wiki/Happiness